# how to ignore duplicate record in a datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

how to ignore duplicate record in a datagrid? and how can i check duplicate record in datagrid...i am using ArrayCollection as a dataprovider to datagrid...

Comment: [Check this out](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/removing-duplicate-items-from-an-array-using-the-arrayfilter-method/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way datagrid itself can do it. I do not know where you get the data, if you cannot avoid getting duplicates being filled/load to arraycollection at first place, I would just remove duplicate records manually from arraycollection before setting to datagrid. If you cannot change the arraycollection, you can do it by creating filterFunction (will look for the item in arraycollection with lower index or so...).